# Combining two LINQ conditionals in where clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have a collection which I query like below.

```
this.Collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.FirstName = "FirstName" && x => x.LastName= "LastName");
```

Now based on a boolean value, I want to add another && condition to the where clause.

How would I go about doing that? I tried the below.

```
var firstExpr = x => x.FirstName = "FirstName" && x => x.LastName= "LastName";
var newExpr = firstExpr;
if (includeAge)
{
 Expression<Func<T, bool>> ageExpr = x => x.Age == 21;
 var combined = Expression.AndAlso(ageExpr.Body, firstExpr.Body);
 var newExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(combined);
}

this.this.Collection.AsQueryable().Where(newExpr);
```

But I get an exception - System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration

Comment: What line is it saying the incorrect number of paramembers? On newExpr right?

Answer (score 4):

If this is an in memory collect, there's no reason to convert to queryable:

```
IEnumerable<YourType> query = this.Collection.Where(x => x.FirstName = "FirstName" && x => x.LastName= "LastName");

if (includeAge)
    query = query.Where(x => x.Age == 21);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryable = this.Collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.FirstName = "FirstName" && x => x.LastName= "LastName");

if (!includeAge)
{
    return queryable;
}

return queryable.Where(x => x.Age == 21);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution to your problem.

```
if (includeAge) {
  firstExpr = firstExpr.Where(n => n.Age == 21);
}
```

Unless you want it in a newExpr... in which case you can just keep var newExpr up top then assign it as above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
var persons = new Person[] {
    new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Appleseed", IsHuman = true },
    new Person() { FirstName = "Compu", LastName = "Tron", IsHuman = false }, 
    new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Tron", IsHuman = false } 
                           };

var wheres = new List<Func<Person, bool>>();

bool filterForJohn = true;
bool filterForHuman = false;

if (filterForJohn)
    wheres.Add(new Func<Person, bool>(p => p.FirstName == "John"));

if (filterForHuman)
    wheres.Add(new Func<Person, bool>(p => p.IsHuman));

IEnumerable<Person> results = persons;

foreach (var where in wheres)
    results = results.Where(where);

foreach (var p in results)
    Console.WriteLine(p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName);
```